# Force to not use a field in group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a list of stores and the turnover:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN SELLER_ID IN ('X','Y') THEN 'SALON' ELSE STORES_ID END AS 'STORES', 
SUM (TURNOVER)
FROM PIECE
GROUP BY STORES_ID ,SELLER_ID
```

The problem is that I don't want to use the field `SELLER_ID` in the group by:

Result:

```
STORE TURNOVER
S1    500
S1    500
S2    600
S2    600
S3    550
S3    550
```

Excepted result: I want to have the sum turnover for each store in one row, but I want only to divis one store in 2 rows when SELLER_ID IN ('X','Y')

Let's say that S3 it's the store that I want to devis:

```
S1     500
S2     300
S3     250
SALON  200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `CASE` statement in your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN SELLER_ID IN ('X','Y') THEN 'SALON' ELSE STORES_ID END AS 'STORES', 
SUM (TURNOVER)
FROM PIECE
GROUP BY CASE WHEN SELLER_ID IN ('X','Y') THEN 'SALON' ELSE STORES_ID END
```